# Docker Maven Telegram Bot Project

Tags: java, docker, maven-dependency

```
# Use an official OpenJDK runtime as a parent image
FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8

# Create new app directory
RUN mkdir /app

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Maven project files
COPY pom.xml /app
COPY src/main/java /app

# Compile the Java source code
RUN mvn compile

# Specify the command to run on container start
CMD ["mvn", "exec:java"]
```

I have edited the code to solve the docker build issue, but I have another issue in docker run, that is :

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:java (default-cli) on project SimpleTelegram: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:java are missing or invalid

Comment: I'm afraid you are trying to do 4 things at once, without understanding any of these - e.g. when using Maven, you'll never manually call `javac`

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do 4 things at once, after I remove the javac, it lead to could not find main

Comment: That's because you have to *use* maven. Just having a pom.xml isn't enough.